# Python Google Maps API not returning the same time as Google Maps website

Tags: python, google-maps, matrix, match, distance

I'm trying to use the Google Maps API to extract the time required to drive between two locations, but the URL request doesn't seem to match the results from the Google Maps website.

For example, if I write a url that I expect to give me the time between Los Angeles and San Diego, and copy the following link into my browser (I could add my key):

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units=imperial&avoid=tolls&origins=Los+Angeles,+CA&destinations=San+Diego,+CA`

I currently get a result suggesting it will take 2 hrs and 3 mins. But if I just type Los Angeles and San Diego into Google Maps it estimates the time at 2 hrs and 9 mins.

Can anyone tell from this information what I'm doing wrong? Please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you expect the times to be the same?  Are the starting and ending locations the same?

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to check the url against google maps, so the starting and ending locations are the same for both. The driving time returned by the url and google maps is different even if I try actual addresses, such as my home and work address. Additionally, when I try my home and work addresses, the driving time doesn't ever seem to change with traffic (it always gives the same answer).

Comment: Just to answer my own question in case someone reads this in the future: the times won't match unless the url returns a "duration in traffic" heading. That heading can only be obtained if the url provides a departure time (e.g. departure_time=now) and you use your API key. The following url works if you include your own key:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units=imperial&avoid=tolls&departure_time=now&origins=Los+Angeles,+CA&destinations=San+Diego,+CA&key=MY_KEY

Comment: you have to provide the same departure time because the traffic will vary depending of the time of the day

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't expect the Web Services API and the Google Maps website to work in the exact same way. These are different products managed by different teams at Google. The search stack is also different, so results may differ.

Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310559/google-map-api-get-duration-without-traffic/38315070#38315070) to get more details