# Google Map API Get Duration without traffic

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I know that the durationIntraffic is depracated now.
I just cant find a way to get the duration without traffic using google api.
already tried the matrix using DrivingOptions and trafficModel but the duration and duration_in_traffic did not match the duration without traffic in Maps.Google.com

Any help on how to get the duration without traffic data using API?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thPH5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duration gives average time  and duration in Traffic gives time in traffic .sometimes you run googleApi  at midnignt you will find duration in Traffic time is lesser than duration time means duration is not without traffic time.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/) Google Maps API should return an element called duration as well as an element called duration_in_traffic. Duration will be time without traffic while duration_in_traffic is time with traffic conditions.

Comment: But when you compare the result from maps.google and google API
the result of duration in API is equal to Duration in Google Maps with traffic.
this [google maps](https://www.google.com.ph/maps/dir/40.7215168,-73.9973206/40.7497269,-73.9877399/@40.7356412,-74.0079833,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!4m1!3e0)
and this [Google API](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&mode=driving&origin=17%20Cleveland%20Pl,%20New%20York,%20NY%2010012,%20USA&destination=60%20W%2034th%20St,%20New%20York,%20NY%2010001,%20USA&departure_time=now&key=AIzaSyBFrkjGbSvrlF4o-Wsoxpi3M5Z7RzjN4BM)

Comment: @JesseCastro And? Did it work? Did it not work? If not why? What is the url you are calling and what is the response? We kinda need more detail about what you have tried so far.

Comment: this [google maps](https://www.google.com.ph/maps/dir/40.7215168,-73.9973206/40.7497269,-73.9877399/@40.7356412,-74.0079833,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!4m1!3e0) and this [Google API](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&mode=driving&origin=17%20Cleveland%20Pl,%20New%20York,%20NY%2010012,%20USA&destination=60%20W%2034th%20St,%20New%20York,%20NY%2010001,%20USA&departure_time=now&key=AIzaSyBFrkjGbSvrlF4o-Wsoxpi3M5Z7RzjN4BM) has the same origin and location. But their result is different. What I really need is to get the W/o traffic value from maps.Google.

Comment: @JesseCastro Yes I see that. The second link you sent me for Google API has both a duration property and a duration_in_traffic property. You need the duration property.

Comment: But the duration property also vary from traffic also.I swear, I tried to refresh the page couple of times and the value of both duration and duration_in_traffic change. What I need is the constant data of duration without traffic.

Comment: @JesseCastro duration shouldn't change unless you change the route or something like that. Anyway you can give more information like a screenshot or something before and after of it changing or something like that? I believe you but I kinda have to see it in order to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to set the correct expectations, you shouldn't expect the Web Services API and the Google Maps website to work in the exact same way. These are different products managed by different teams at Google. The search stack is also different, so results may differ.

The result you get in duration field is an approximation of the average travel time for the route. This takes into account average traffic conditions of the last several weeks for a time when you execute a request. That means that the duration can change during the day.

Applying the departure time and traffic_model you can add further information to your requests to get the travel time in the current traffic, this will be provided in a duration_in_traffic field.

Resuming, currently there is no way to get duration without traffic. You will get the average travel time via the API.